# Django OAuth Toolkit error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "oauth2_provider_accesstoken_pkey"

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to run a React Native app using a Django backend in a simulator. However, when I try to log in on the app, I get the following error from the Django development server:

```
[17/Jul/2018 16:46:17] "GET /dashboard/login?next=/api/2/me/apn/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4588
(0.001) SELECT typarray FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'citext'; args=None
(0.004) SELECT "oauth2_provider_application"."id", "oauth2_provider_application"."client_id", "oauth2_provider_application"."user_id", "oauth2_provider_application"."redirect_uris", "oauth2_provider_application"."client_type", "oauth2_provider_application"."authorization_grant_type", "oauth2_provider_application"."client_secret", "oauth2_provider_application"."name", "oauth2_provider_application"."skip_authorization", "oauth2_provider_application"."created", "oauth2_provider_application"."updated" FROM "oauth2_provider_application" WHERE "oauth2_provider_application"."client_id" = '1rZrEiL8UpKI8wQjUrvDS3i4h536DdS9YbFwIhPq'; args=('1rZrEiL8UpKI8wQjUrvDS3i4h536DdS9YbFwIhPq',)
(0.005) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."username" = 'kurt@hicleo.com'; args=('kurt@hicleo.com',)
(0.050) INSERT INTO "oauth2_provider_accesstoken" ("user_id", "token", "application_id", "expires", "scope", "created", "updated") VALUES (2018, '77km8bPCu1iyDyMsZI2cDsi3vkmFb6', 1, '2018-08-16T23:46:37.800702+00:00'::timestamptz, 'read write', '2018-07-17T23:46:37.801418+00:00'::timestamptz, '2018-07-17T23:46:37.801431+00:00'::timestamptz) RETURNING "oauth2_provider_accesstoken"."id"; args=(2018, '77km8bPCu1iyDyMsZI2cDsi3vkmFb6', 1, datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 16, 23, 46, 37, 800702, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'read write', datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 23, 46, 37, 801418, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 23, 46, 37, 801431, tzinfo=<UTC>))
Internal Server Error: /o/token/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "oauth2_provider_accesstoken_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1042) already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2_provider/views/base.py", line 185, in post
    url, headers, body, status = self.create_token_response(request)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2_provider/views/mixins.py", line 125, in create_token_response
    return core.create_token_response(request)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2_provider/oauth2_backends.py", line 139, in create_token_response
    headers, extra_credentials)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/endpoints/base.py", line 64, in wrapper
    return f(endpoint, uri, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/endpoints/token.py", line 117, in create_token_response
    request, self.default_token_type)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/grant_types/resource_owner_password_credentials.py", line 109, in create_token_response
    self.request_validator.save_token(token, request)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/request_validator.py", line 246, in save_token
    return self.save_bearer_token(token, request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2_provider/oauth2_validators.py", line 464, in save_bearer_token
    access_token = self._create_access_token(expires, request, token)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2_provider/oauth2_validators.py", line 489, in _create_access_token
    access_token.save()
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 808, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 838, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 924, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 963, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1076, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1112, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "oauth2_provider_accesstoken_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1042) already exists.

(0.006) SELECT "oauth2_provider_accesstoken"."id", "oauth2_provider_accesstoken"."user_id", "oauth2_provider_accesstoken"."token", "oauth2_provider_accesstoken"."application_id", "oauth2_provider_accesstoken"."expires", "oauth2_provider_accesstoken"."scope", "oauth2_provider_accesstoken"."created", "oauth2_provider_accesstoken"."updated" FROM "oauth2_provider_accesstoken" LIMIT 21; args=()
[17/Jul/2018 16:46:38] "POST /o/token/ HTTP/1.1" 500 276302
```

How to overcome this error? Do I have to first manually drop/delete this access token from the database?

Comment: can you give more detail about your code - view that occured this error?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, for me, delete refresh tokens table fixed the problem (but I think this is a bug).
I also updated the package to 1.1.2 (remember migrations after update)